# How to escape curly braces in RegExp

Tags: ios, angular, regex

I want to escape curly braces in my regular expression. Unfortunately the `\\` does not work. The problem is that the regular expression does not work on IOS mobile devices.

The regular expression is used in Angular forms:

```
Validators.pattern('(?<!\w)(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}(?!\w)');
```

Whenever I enter the site that does use this expression on IOS mobile device, then I can see in chrome errors related to regular expression. If I delete this pattern, then the site works without any problems.

Comment: Why do you want to double escape the curly's? What is the tool or language, where are you typing the number?

Comment: So I do use Angular. The problem is that the pattern does not work on IOS mobile device. I have read that you need to escape curly braces to make it work.

Comment: Maybe the lookbehind is not supported. It will give you these matches, where the lookbehind will skip the `+` sign and get a partial match. See https://regex101.com/r/jeOF7P/1 If you want to validate the whole string, you might us anchors https://regex101.com/r/DWO5aU/1

Comment: The problem is that these regular expressions still does not work on IOS mobile and chromium. I have read that you need to escape the curly braces to make it work, that's why I have asked how to correctly escape them. I.e the {3}.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant part of the code that you are using so readers can have a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pass RegExp instance instead of direct string

```
Validators.pattern(new RegExp(/^(?<!\w)(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}(?!\w)$/, 'i'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This validation looks suspicious: `(?<!\w)`/`(?!\w)` unambiguous word boundaries are used to circumvent the problem with `\b` word boundaries when there is a chance that the adjoining character type may be different (word and non-word). **It only makes sense when you match whole words in a longer string**.

Angular validation for a phone number is meant to match the whole string, so I recommend *just removing these lookarounds*. You do not even need to add `^` at the start and `$` at the end since these anchors are added by Angular to any regex passed to `Validators.pattern()` as a string literal, `"..."` (as opposed to regex literal, `/.../`).

However, it is not all: you are defining the regex with a string literal, so you need to double the backslashes in your string.

You can use

```js
Validators.pattern('(\\(?(\\+|00)?48\\)?)?[ -]?\\d{3}[ -]?\\d{3}[ -]?\\d{3}');
```